# Backend Java application testing using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a Java program which works on backend .It's a kind of batch processing type where I will have a text file that contains messages.The Java program will fetch message from text file and will load in to DB or Mainframe.Instead of sequential fetching we need to try parallel  fetching .How can I do through Jmeter?

I tried my converting the program to a Jar file and calling it through class name.
Also tried by pasting code and in argument place we kept the CSV (the text file converted to .CSV).

Both of this giving Sampler client exception..

Can you please help me how to proceed or is there something we are missing or other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to kick off multiple instances of your program is running it via JMeter's [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) which can run arbitrary commands and print their output + measure execution time.

If you have your program as an [executable jar](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/85application/jar/jar.html) you can kick it off like:

[image: JMeter OS Process Sampler Execute Jar]

See [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) article for more information on the approach